# Jquery Show Hide div on dropdown change not working properly while Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

**Problem:** I am using Jquery for Show / Hide div on `dropdown` change on my application , when I am creating new Form its working better, but when i update it, the form getting collapsed to normal view and I'm not getting the one which I should view , so that is making me to change the drop down option again to view the fields which i set to show.

**My JQuery:**

```
<?php 

 $this->registerJs(' 
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(\'.ordinary\').hide(); 
     $(\'.special\').hide();        
 $(\'#company-typeofcompany\').change(function () {
    var x = $(this).val();
    if (x === "ordinary") {
        $(\'.ordinary\').show();  
        $(\'.special\').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $(\'.special\').show();
        $(\'.ordinary\').hide(); 
    }
});

});', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);

?>
```

Comment: if the code is fixed the instead of registering using yii2's tool you can add it like native code into the page below your html code & see the errors on event. that will probably help solve problem occuring

Comment: i diidn't get any error

Comment: once i change the dropdown and selected, i need to view show div always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess on update you have to check the condition of the dropdown value and if it is ordinary you have to show the normal and hide the special and viceversa for another value. The code might be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ordinary').hide(); 
     $('.special').hide();
     if ($('#company-typeofcompany').val() == "ordinary") {
         $('.ordinary').show();  
         $('.special').hide();
     } else {
         $('.special').show();
         $('.ordinary').hide(); 
     }
     $('#company-typeofcompany').change(function () {
         var x = $(this).val();
         if (x === "ordinary") {
             $('.ordinary').show();  
             $('.special').hide();
         } else {
             $('.special').show();
             $('.ordinary').hide(); 
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Then your dropdown would have ordinary as preselected, change that
if ($('#company-typeofcompany').val() == "ordinary") { to 
if ($('#company-typeofcompany').val() == "special") {
and also show me the console.log($('#company-typeofcompany').val())

Comment: if i change it to special, now ordinary not getting hide , it always showing

Comment: what about console.log($('#company-typeofcompany').val());

Comment: you telling me to write console.log in jquery. is it right??

Comment: yeah.... you have to see what is the value set in that option box and then we can debug where the problem exists